# XStream - package tag getting printed below xml tag

Tags: xstream

I have used XStream to output my java object to XML. Java classes are client classes generated from WSDL. Output I am getting is like:

```
<ROOT_TAG>
 <sections>
  <com.tarun.local.xstream.test.Sections>
   <position>1</position>
   <rank>1</rank>
  <scores>
   <com.tarun.local.xstream.test.Scores>
    <number>100</number>
   </com.tarun.local.xstream.test.Scores>
  </scores>
 </com.tarun.local.xstream.test.Sections>
 </section>
</ROOT_TAG>
```

How can I remove that extra package tag printed?
Output should be like:

```
<ROOT_TAG>
<sections>      
<position>1</position>
<rank>1</rank>
<scores>       
<number>100</number>       
</scores>     
</section>
</ROOT_TAG>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply alias, [via code](http://xstream.codehaus.org/alias-tutorial.html) or [annotations](http://xstream.codehaus.org/annotations-tutorial.html):

```
@XStreamAlias("section")
@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="part")
```

Comment: I used alias. But alias is replacing "<com.tarun.local.xstream.test.Sections>" with "sections" and I am getting below structure after that.

<ROOT_TAG>
<sections>
<sections>
<position>1</position>
<rank>1</rank>
<scores>
<scores>
<number>100</number>
</scores>
</scores>
<sections>
</sections>
</ROOT_TAG>

How do I remove those duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to omit that field, so the answer will be :

```
XStream x = new XStream();
x.omitField(A.class, "com.tarun.local.xstream.test.Sections");
x.omitField(A.class, "com.tarun.local.xstream.test.Scores");
```